# Opening a desktop app from Gtalk

Tags: html, google-talk

I am kinda having a strange requirement. I have a google talk bot & a standalone app installed in the PC. On giving some command to the bot, the bot should be able to send a link clicking on which it opens the app on the desktop.

For eg. I have downloaded an app called MyCalendar. the google bot should give me a link, clicking on which MyCalendar app should open in desktop.

I don't know if that's possible really. I have figured one way of doing this by giving the URL of a page on my server opening which it opens the desktop app like how Apple Appstore website opens ITunes.

Is there any there better way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: You could look at the /exec plugin for pidgin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are really asking is: how to register a desktop app to handle custom url scheme?

This is really OS dependent:

OS X: http://cocoadev.com/wiki/HowToRegisterURLHandler

Windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx

Comment: Okay. What I really wanted to understand was can I send a clickable link to this custom URL as a chat on Google IM?

Comment: Why don't you type a custom url (e.g. `myapp://something`) into Google IM and find out if it comes out on the other side as a clickable link?